# Login System: Multi-User (Admin & User)

Tags: php, mysql

Each time I login with a user account, it takes me to the admin page and not the user page. Also, I have used hash for securing password but each time I try to login with the correct password it won't work.

I can login with Admin and User Accounts. However, the password is hashed so it doesn't work, when I try to login with it. Also I get errors when I logout. The only way I can login is, if I manually change the password which is showing as hashed on mysql database, by changing it to what it originally was (BUT THIS THEN MEANS THE PASSWORD CAN BE SEEN BY EVERYONE OF THAT USER, AS i have manually changed it).

```
<?php
session_start();
$heading = 'Login/Register';
require 'layout.php';
?>

<?php
$server = 'v.je';
$username = 'student';
$password = 'student';

$schema = 'csy2028';
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password,
[ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

if (isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_encrypted = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password)
    VALUES(:name, :email, :username, :password)");

    $insert->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $insert->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $insert->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $insert->bindParam(':password', $password_encrypted);
    $insert->execute();
}
else if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $us=$_POST['userType'];

    $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and userType='$us' ");
    $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $select->execute();

    $data=$select->fetch();
    $admin = "admin/ham123";
    $admin = "admin";

    if($data['username']!=$username && $data['password']!=$password){
        echo "invalid username or password";
    }
    else if($data['username']==$username && $data['password']==$password){
        $_SESSION['adminloggedin']=$data['email'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];

    header("location:adminprofile.php");
    }

    else if($data['username']==$username && $data['password']==$password &&     $us==$data['userType']){
        $_SESSION['email']=$data['email'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];

    header("location:userprofile.php");
    }
}

?>
<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Login</legend>
<label for='username' >Username:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" />
<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
<select name="userType" >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select User Type</option>
            <option value="User">User</option>
            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
        </select>
        <label>User Type</label>
<button class="button" name="login" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Login</span></button>
</fieldset>
</form>

<form id='register' action='login.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset >
<legend>Register User</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<label for='name' >Name: </label>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" />
<label for='email' >Email:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" />
<label for='username' >Username:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" />
<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
<button class="button" name="signup" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Register</span></button>
</fieldset>
</form>

<?php
require 'footer.php'
?>
```

Comment: No no no this is not how you should use `password_hash()` .. You only should select the record based on username from the database and do `password_verify()` on the posted password and records password to prevent timing attacks.. Also your SQL is prone to SQL injections.

Comment: See more about mine comment here in the [Manual (Safe Password Hashing)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Hi this isn't working.    else if($data['username']==$username && password_verify ($password , $data['password']) &&  $us==$data['userType']){
  $_SESSION['email']=$data['email'];
  $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];

 header("location:userprofile.php");
 }
}

Comment: Hi Guys. Still not working. Maybe It's just me. I might be not putting the right code. Sorry i'm new to PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your password verifying code `$data['password']==$password`, it should be:

```
password_verify ($password , $data['password'])
```

**EDIT**

You have some more problems. This select:

```
 $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and userType='$us' ");
 $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $select->execute();
```

Will never return you anything, because you hashed your password to store it in DB and know you are comparing it with the plain text password. You should change it to:

```
$select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and userType='$us' ");
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
```

Now you can get the password hash from DB and compare it. So the rest of the code should be:

```
if(!password_verify ($password , $data['password'])){
        echo "invalid username or password";
    } else if($data['userType']=='admin'){
        $_SESSION['adminloggedin']=$data['email'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];
        header("location:adminprofile.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['email']=$data['email'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];
        header("location:userprofile.php");
    }
```

You don´t need to verify the user, because you already loocked for it in your DB. So if the password is wrong, you get the error message, and if it is ok you test if the user type is 'admin' (or whatever you need). If it is ok you get in as admin, otherways you get in as user.

Comment: Thanks you guys. Would you know what's wrong, when a user logs in. Why it goes to the admin panel and not user?

Comment: NOT WORKING.     else if($data['username']==$username && password_verify ($password , $data['password']) &&  $us==$data['userType']){
  $_SESSION['email']=$data['email'];
  $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];

 header("location:userprofile.php");
 }
}

Comment: most likely the statements needs to check more strict more or less like `else if($data['username']==$username && $data['password']==$password) &&     $data['userType'] == 'admin'` ?? `else if($data['username']==$username && $data['password']==$password) &&     $data['userType'] == 'user'` ? @user9036433

Comment: Hi Guys. Still not working. Maybe It's just me. I might be not putting the right code. Sorry i'm new to PHP and MySQL.